# Application Crash problem on second time click on Menu Arrow of QToolButton

Tags: qt

In my APPlication I have to show filter option (as filter option in xls)in Qtable widget for this 
     I have used tool Button( with property "QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup") to display Menu List and 
Upon First Click upon Menu arrow it should show Menu list and selection of any of the Menu it should show only row having the text.
This functionality works fine.
        But if Nothing is selected from Menu list and user has clicked Menu arrow second time then list should be hidden but in my case 
application crashes giving error:

ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", file ........\Qt\2010.04\qt\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 447

I have written below code:

```
 QToolButton *lToolButton = new QToolButton();
 lToolButton->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
 lToolButton->setAutoRaise(true);
 lToolButton->setText("Filter");
 QMenu *lMenu = new QMenu();
 QAction *lAction = new QAction("All",this);
 lMenu->addAction(lAction);
 lToolButton->setMenu(lMenu);
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my coding.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your app in the debugger and find at what line *in your code* (not in Qt's code) the error is happening? The problem should then because more obvious.